# Genetic Programming Python library with a Scikit-Learn inspired API

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, genetic-programming

I've been working with GPlearn for the passed couple of months as part of my research, but it turns out that it provides only a binary symbolic classifier. Do you guys know any other python library which do provide non-binary symbolic classifier and is scikit-learn based API?

Thanks!

Comment: GPlearn also does regression from the doc. Do you mean multi-class classification with genetic programming?

Comment: Yes. Multi-class classification with genetic programming (symbolic classification)